# Trying to understand Anonymous Function in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand the code which is present in the line

```
list = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((data) => PhotoData.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
```

I have the following questions 
a) What does .map do ?
b) What is 'data' in the above code
c) Could you please simplify the code into long form so that I can better grasp it.

The complete function is listed as below:

```
_fetchData() async {

  http.Response response =
      await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
  print("Fetching data...");
  list = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
      .map((data) => PhotoData.fromJson(data))
      .toList();
  setState(() {
    isLoading =false;
  });
}




factory PhotoData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return PhotoData( json['id'], json['title'],
      json['thumbnailUrl'], json['url']);
}
```

Comment: `map()` method modifies your input Iterable by calling the mapper function for each input element, for example try this: `var array = [1,3,4,7];
  var mappedArray = array.map((i) {
    return i * 10;
  });
  print(array);
  print(mappedArray);`

Comment: If I am able to understand correctly from the code that you have provided , the variable i is not defined in the scope but belongs to anonymous function and .map function takes each data item from the list or the array and can be provided for operation in anonymous function  ..is that correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct, however `map` does not need anonymous function - you can also use it like this: `map(mappingFunction)` where mapper function is a normal function (or method) like `int mappingFunction(int item) {...`

Comment: Thank You so I have been at it since the last 2 days ,You explanation clarified it

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: **EDIT**: my first comment is wrong: `"modifies your input Iterable"` is not true, i used "mental shortcut" - `map()` method creates a brand new object, it does not change the original object, the docs say: *"Returns a new lazy Iterable with elements that are created by calling f on each element of this Iterable in iteration order."*

Comment: I read the documentation(Hence the use of .toList() at the end ), Could you if possible explain it a bit more ?

Comment: i mean that original `var array` is not modified by `map()` method

Comment: Ok, Is there a resource to know more about Iterables because Dart documentation seems to be really concise. Ty

Comment: ask google for: `dart iterables`, for example: https://codeburst.io/top-10-array-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart-feb2648ee3a2 and https://codingwithjoe.com/dart-fundamentals-working-with-lists/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is a method inside class `Iterable`. Since class [`List`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/core/list.dart) implements `EfficientLengthIterable<E>` therefore it inherits the method `map`.

According to the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html), the map does the following:

> Returns a new lazy Iterable with elements that are created by calling f on each element of this Iterable in iteration order.

---

This is the implemenation of the `map` method:

```
Iterable<T> map<T>(T f(E e)) => MappedIterable<E, T>(this, f);
```

`Iterable<T>` => this means that the `map` method will return an Iterable

`f(E e)` => means that `map` will contain a function with element of type `E`

`=>` the arrow is a shorthand of writing return

---

Example:

```
class Person 
{
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  Person(this.firstName, this.lastName);
}

void main() {
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
  people.add(new Person("Joe", "Smithers"));
  people.add(new Person("Patrick", "Thomas"));
  var mappedNames = people.map<String>((Person n) => 'Mr. ${n.firstName} ${n.lastName}');
  print(mappedNames);
}
```

In this example `map` returns an iterable of type `String`, thus you can add `map<String>`, and variable `n` is of type `Person`, thus you can write `Person n`.

The type of `n` is equivalent to the type of variable `people`. Since here basically `map` method is iterating inside the list `people` and returning a new `Iterable` according to what you wrote in the return statement.

Therefore `print(mappedNames)` will give you the following:

```
(Mr. Joe Smithers, Mr. Patrick Thomas)
```

[*Note*](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts): you dont have to add the types since dart infers the type.

---

In your code you have the following:

```
list = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((data) => PhotoData.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
```

`(json.decode(response.body) as List)` which means that you are casting the json object to type `List`, then using `map` you iterate inside of it and return an iterable.

Then you use [`toList()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html) to create a `List` from the returned `iterable`

Comment: So basically to put it in the simplest way ,It picks up an element from the list and then this can be worked upon one by one in the anonymous function ,As you have pointed out using Person n as a variable since each iterable to be read was going to be of the same type ...is that so ?

Comment: Yes, as in the `Person` example it will iterate inside the list `people` of type `Person` and return the firstname and last name in an iterable according to the output of `print(mappedNames)`

Comment: I just have one more question to add to this ? Can you please explain where does 'data' originate from or what it is ;this is giving me hell

Comment: As I told u 'map` contains a nameless function inside of it(anonymous function). In any function you may have parameter or not. In this case `data` is the parameter. It's the same as `map((Person n)`,which can also be written as `map((n)`

Comment: It's the same as this in javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I am sorry but coming from java background does make it kind of difficult to understand it ... However after reading a bit more it seems to me that it works more like    future.then((String val) => print(val)); passing the value from the future into the anonymous function ...Hope that's correct

Comment: its the same as `map` in java 8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: look this is the `map` in java  `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.stream().map(new Function<String,String>()
  {

   @Override
   public String apply(String t)
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
   }
  });` .......if you apply the lambda it will become like this `list.stream().map(t -> null);`